# Pydev doesn't find miniupnpc library after installation

Tags: python, python-3.x, miniupnpc

I installed via `pip install miniupnpc` and the installation seemed to be going fine.

A library called `miniupnpc.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` was created in site-packages.

Yet PyDev doesn't think this library exists. `import miniupnpc` results into a `Unresolved import` error.

Rescanning the PyDev Interpreter didn't help.